# CakePHP : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 52 bytes)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, fatal-error

Hi i have a apps running on `CakePHP v 1.3`. I've updated my `wamp` server to `v2.4`.After updating i got this error message.I did these changes into my php.ini settings.

---

- memory_limit = 128M
- file_uploads = ON
- upload_max_filesize = 128M
- max_input_time
- max_execution_time = 300
- post_max_size = 128M
- realpath_cache_size = 16k
- realpath_cache_ttl = 120

But i'm still getting these Error message :

```
CakePHP : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 52 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\gtgcrm\cake\libs\model\
datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php on line 775
```

What i missed ? Any Suggestion will be appreciated !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can increase memory limit by using in your controller action

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Also you can increase time out limit

```
set_time_limit(0); Infinite
```

Comment: To enable this for all controllers, you can put the init_set inside AppController -> `public function initialize() { ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); ...}`

Answer (score 6):

Increase memory limit in `php.ini`, this is not is appropriate solution at all.

> this case can be also occurred from code e.g infinite loop, process
>   large amount data, or even database queries You should check code,
>   there might have been infinite loop or such type case.

Answer (score 3):

The error is obvious and it is due to exceeding memory limits by setting in your ini files or .htaccess. You can also set via php as Anubhay wrote. Following variables are your concern

```
php_value post_max_size 1000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2500M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
php_value max_input_time 6000000
php_value memory_limit 2500M
```

You can optimize query data by using cake behavior containable. It is better practice to optimize your code/data rather than increasing memory size.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Try...
Allowed memory size 
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: Please elaborate on why this might solve the problem.