# CakePHP fatal error allowed memory size of bytes exhausted - only for one record. Maybe MySQL index issue?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This is really weird. I am getting "fatal error allowed memory size of bytes exhausted" when trying to open Views (view and edit) for a particular record (primary id = 1).

The error message is:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 79 bytes) in 
/myappname/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php
on line 276
```

The views are plain straight from Cake Bake All views, and they work for all other records (eg id = 2 and up).

The issue exists on both my local dev env and on prod hosted env.

It appears that  the issue would be the record itself eg content of record.

However, I can do select * from table where id = 1 no problem in both dev & prod databases.  I also  copied the record id = 1 to a new record with MySQL. This new record works in views no problem.

To try to debug, I put:

```
pr($helperClass);die
```

before the Mysql.php on line 276 where error happens. The debug message is:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected '$resultRow' (T_VARIABLE)
File: myappname\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Mysql.php
Line: 277
```

I know that the 'Allowed memory size exhausted' error indicates a php.ini value for memory is not adequate for whatever is happening, but rather than increase this I would like to determine what is causing this.

Any ideas what could be causing this and what the debug  'unexpected $resultRow' message is about?  Any other debug suggestions welcomed too.

Don't think the code is going to be helpful. It is a plain jane baked app with 4 tables:

1. Cards
2. Comments
3. Countries
4. Users

Countries 
 Users

CakePHP Models:

- Country hasMany: Comment, User
- Card belongsTo: Country, User
- Card hasMany: Comment
- Comment belongsTo: Card, Country, User
- User belongsTo: Country
- User hasMany: Card, Comment

CakePHP View Controller:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Country->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid country'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Country.' . $this->Country->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('country', $this->Country->find('first', $options));
}
```

CakePHP View:

```
<div class="countries view">
<h2><?php echo __('Country'); ?> - <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $country['Country']['id'])); ?></h2>
    <dl>
        <dt><?php echo __('Id'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($country['Country']['id']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Country'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($country['Country']['country']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
        <dt><?php echo __('Country Code'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($country['Country']['country_code']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: mysql indexes have NOTHING to do with php memory. you're simply trying to load too much into PHP. e.g. pouring 10 gallons of water into a 1 ounce cup.

Comment: So if I copy the 10 gallon record to a new record why does it appear to have 1 ounce?  Can MySQL index be corrupted somehow that gives it 10 gallons worth of memory?

Comment: indexes are there to help find things faster. without an index you'd still get EXACTLY the same results, just slower. Think of mysql's index like a card catalogue in the library. If you look in the catalogue, you can go right to the shelf that has the book(s) you need. Without the card catalogue, you have to look through every book. But all of that is done in the database. the ONLY stuff that gets transferred to your client are the results of the query. not the entire database.

Comment: and since you haven't shown any actual code, we can't really explain what the problem is, other tahn trying to load too much data. if you're doing `select ....`, stuffing all of the results into a php array, then doing `insert ...` or `update ...` later on, then yeah, you're sucking across 10 gallons. but that's not php's fault. it's just doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I suspect this is a CakePHP issue rather than MySQL or PHP.

Comment: `die` is missing at least a closing semicolon...

Comment: Mind sharing the code that triggers this error?

Comment: Added CakePHP controller, model and view code. Won't be helpful .

Comment: Ah, issue found. I totally overlooked something.  I have another table that I hadn't yet (purposefully) integrated into app yet.  It has 1000's of records per country.  Country pk id = 1 has more than others. At some point, I had added this other table to country model hasMany relationship. So CakePHP was pulling other table records behind scenes which is what was bunging up memory. It hadn't been a problem until now though. Anyways issue found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 52 bytes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650692/cakephp-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-536870912-bytes-exhausted-tried-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was another table that I hadn't yet (purposefully) integrated into app yet.

It has 1000's of records per country. Country pk id = 1 has more than others.

At some point, I had added this other table to Country model's hasMany relationship.

So CakePHP was pulling other table records behind scenes which is what was bunging up memory.

It hadn't been a problem until now though so this other table must now have more records and just tipped the scales.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase memory limit by using in your controller action

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
Also you can increase time out limit

set_time_limit(0); Infinite